# ndk-build.cmd failed during compilation (opencv face detect)

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I know there was a lot of similar topics but none of them helped and belive I'm trying to run this for over 2 days.
I want to run face detection sample and I'm stuck on ndk build

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include C:/Users/dpach/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "threewe.testopencv"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        commandLine 'C:\\Users\\dpach\\android-ndk-r12\\ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('jni').absolutePath
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
    compile project(':libraries:opencv')
}
```

error

```
System nie moľe odnale«† okre?lonej ?cieľki.
make: *** [C:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/detection_based_tracker/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `C:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/jni'
:app:ndkBuild FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\dpach\android-ndk-r12\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Translation of the error: 'System cannot find specified path'

I've checked the path and it exists I even put there file from another project but the result is the same. I've tried also to run ndk-build.cmd manualy from the console but the result is the same so this is not Android Studio issue. I have no idea what more I can do :(

// EDIT

added `V=1` parameter

```
make: Entering directory `C:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/jni'
[armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "detection_based_tracker <= DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp"
C:/Users/dpach/android-ndk-r12/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF C:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/detection_based_tracker/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes  -g -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/dpach/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv" -I"C:/Users/dpach/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include" -IC:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/jni -IC:/Users/dpach/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/dpach/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -IC:/Users/dpach/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/jni -DANDROID -fPIC -DANDROID -fsigned-char -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -frtti -fexceptions  -isystem C:/Users/dpach/android-ndk-r12/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-arm/usr/include -c  C:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/jni/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp -o C:/Users/dpach/AndroidStudioProjects/TestOpenCv/app/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/detection_based_tracker/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.o
```

Comment: Run `ndk-build V=1` from command line (don't forget the correct `-C`), and you will see what compilation step caused the problem. Are you sure that **DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp** file is in the same **jni** directory as **Android.mk**?

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks for your time. I've added the parameter and pasted the output in the topic. Can you advice on it ? Yes, I'm sure that this .cpp file is in the jni directory as Android.mk

Comment: check that file C:/Users/dpach/android-ndk-r12/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ also exists. Maybe you should download the updated version of NDK r12.

Comment: @AlexCohn I have directory `windows` not `windowsx86_64` and in it is the file you've mentioned. I've downloaded ndk yestrday

Comment: @AlexCohn that was the answer. The missing directory I've copied and renamed it so the name was as you've mentioned and it went through whole proces. Thank you very much

Comment: So, this smells like a bug in the latest version of NDK for Windows?

Comment: @AlexCohn yes it smells like a bug

Comment: Looking more carefully at what happens on the download page, this seems to be a mistake tagging 32- and 64-bit versions. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/127).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug on the download page of NDK, see the [issue](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/127) yours truly opened.

You can use the [wiki page](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki#current-stable-release) on GitHub that is updated more frequently.

In your specific case, your are using 32-bit version on your 64-bit Windows, which is suboptimal. You can download the latest stable version [r12b](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64.zip) for your OS.