# ndk-build command not found in git bash?

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin, git-bash, ndk-build

I am trying to use mupdf for Android.I have installed the ndk from Android Studio Settings.I have also updated my PATH varibale in System variables.But when I type ndk-build in git bash or cygwin I get error:- $ ndk-build bash: ndk-build: command not found.Can anyone guide me?

When I run C:\android-ndk-r12\ndk-build.cmd I get the following warnings and errors.

> Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-24 is larger than
>   android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml Android NDK:
>   WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for
>   static libraries [armeabi-v7a] "Compile thumb  ": "mupdf_java <=
>   mupdf.c" process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL,
>   C:/android-ndk-r12/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf_java/mupdf.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -g -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -Os -DNDEBUG -Ijni/andprof -I../../../include -I../../../source/fitz -I../../../source/pdf -I../../../platform/java -IC:/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/system/include -Ijni -DANDROID -DHAVE_ANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -isystem C:/android-ndk-r12/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include
>   -c jni/mupdf.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf_java/mupdf.o, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf_java/mupdf.o] Error 2

Any help or suggestion is appreciated?

Comment: how have you updated the path ?

Comment: I edited the Path variable text C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.

Comment: edited how?  That format is NOT the cywin posix style;  look on `echo $PATH` for checking.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need ndk-build on your PATH. You can invoke it from command line like this:

```
C:/Users/AndroidNewBee/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build
```

If this does not work, check where you actually unpacked your NDK. It is very important to avoid directories with space in their names, e.g. `Application Data` or whatever.

Second, you don't need cygwin or bash to run ndk-build. You can run it from your Windows CMD window, as

```
C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd
```

If you want to set your PATH to make invocation of ndk-build easier, you need to add the *folder* that contains the command, not the command itself, e.g.

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Please check my updated question. I get these warnings Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-24 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries
[armeabi-v7a] "Compile thumb  ": "mupdf_java <= mupdf.c"

Comment: I believe that your update qualifies as a whole new question.

Comment: The warning says exactly what it is about. Your **Application.mk** should include `APP_PLATFORM:=android-8` if you really need `android:minSdkVersion 8`. You can also provide `APP_PLATFORM=android-8` on `ndk-build` command line if it better suits your environment

Comment: Regarding the error, check if file `C:\android-ndk-r12\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe` exists. Maybe, you will find `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe` under **windows**, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928061. In this case, you should download the fixed [Win-64 NDK](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64.zip).

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the Command not found when navigating to ndk folder, Hence tried with the full path and escaping slash '\' it worked!

```
*Saad@DESKTOP-L2341JS MINGW64 /E/dev/android_sample_master/app/jni*
$ D:\\sdk\\ndk-bundle\\ndk-build.cmd Android.mk
```